# Minify HTML on specific page

Tags: html

im trying to (at first) use PHPWEE's HtmlMin.php minifier to minify the html of a specific page and output it to browser. bellows my code;

```
function minify_html_output(){
// Get page html
$page = get_page_by_title( 'page-title' );
$page_id = $page->ID;
$html_pre_min = get_post_field( 'post_content', $page_id );
// Minify the HTML using PHPWee
require_once('phpwee/src/HtmlMin/HtmlMin.php');
$minified_html = \PHPWee\Minify::html($html_pre_min);
echo $minified_html;
```

}

seems like it should work, it just isnt, what am i doing wrong?

many thanks

Comment: Where are you calling your function? Is it hooked to a filter or an action?

Comment: Im not, im new to coding, what function should I put it in? And can I use it to get all pages & posts